# Назви чоловічих професій, які історично були лише жіночими: ПОВІЯ

Tags: словотворення

Щодо утворення фемінітивів, інформації багацько. А от цікавить те, чи утворюються назви чоловічих професій, які історично були лише жіночими? Якщо так, то як саме? Це стосується, наприклад, такого, як **повія**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До *повії* існує „повнїше“ слово *повійниця*.

Слоўник української мови Грінченка:

> [**Повія**](http://hrinchenko.com//slovar/znachenie-slova/40872-povija.html), **-вії**, *ж.* = **повійниця**. Мир. ХРВ. 313. *Мабуть назнав десь повію всесвітню та й віється*. Мир. ХРВ. 324.
>
> ---
>
> [**Повійниця**](http://hrinchenko.com//slovar/znachenie-slova/40823-povijnycja.html), **-ці**, *ж*. Потаскуха. Мир. ХРВ. 158. *Чи не з повійницею бува якою спізнався*. Мир. ХРВ. 296.

Слоўник української мови в 11 книгах:

> [**Пові́йниця**](http://sum.in.ua/s/povijnycja), **-і**, *жін.*, *рідко*. Те саме, що **пові́я**. *Чи не з повійницею, бува, якою спізнався [Чіпка], то соромно признаватись?..* (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 326).

[Відси](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) нескладно утвороти чоловічого роду: **пові́йник**.

Comment: Це доволі цікава інформація, таке слово ніколи мені не траплялося! Дякую!

Answer (score 2):

## «Проститу́т»

По-перше, слід зазначити, що українська мова, окрім слова «повія», має ще слово «[проститу́тка](http://sum.in.ua/s/prostytutka)». Це не є росіянізмом, адже саме явище в українській мові називається «[проститу́ція](http://sum.in.ua/s/prostytucija)» (і це слово [походить з латини](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prostituta)). Від нього легко утворюється іменник чоловічого роду «проститу́т».

Хоч це слово («проститу́т») і відсутнє у словниках, але значення його очевидне і воно вживається доволі давно (зокрема в переносному значенні — «продажна людина, запроданець»):

- Михайло Грушевський, [«Гімн вдячності»](http://www.m-hrushevsky.name/uk/Publicistics/1910/GimnVdjachnosti.html), зокрема у [книзі 4 то́му 50 «Літературно-наукового вістника»](//books.google.com/books?id=eAhJAQAAMAAJ) (Львів–Київ, 1910):

  > Все вони, все землячки, різних калібрів і категорій, від дешевеньких **проститутів**, що за п’ятачок від стрічки писатиме донос на батька рідного, і до тих, кого доля посадила на верхи сучасної культурності, дала змогу «говорити перед Європою».
- Юрій Мошинський, [«У світі мистецьких чарів. Враження з подорожі»](http://diasporiana.org.ua/mistetstvo/17143-moshinskiy-yu-u-sviti-mistetskih-chariv-vrazhennya-z-podorozhi/) (Чикаго, 1963):

  > Якось не можу себе примусити по­важати вуличних артистів, хоч, може, між ними є й добрі, але думка, що вони себе понижують, торгуючи ескізиками, не давала ніколи спокою й наставляла вороже до артистів-«**проститутів**».

## Інші варіанти

У [словнику Грінченка](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rus&dicts=12), а також інших словниках ([Уманець і Спілка](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=9), [Ніковський](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=8), [Кримський і Єфремов](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=1)) наводяться такі варіанти для слова «проститутка»:

- ба́хурка;
- бендю́жина, биндю́жина;
- бо́ска;
- димтя́нка, діптя́нка;
- па́плюга;
- розтру́ха;
- трав’я́нка;
- финдю́рка;
- фльо́ндра;
- хво́йда;
- хльо́рка.

Від деяких з них, можливо, легше утворити чоловічий рід, ніж від слова «повія», наприклад: «баху́р» ([є в «Словнику української мови», зокрема лайливе в значеннях «розпусник; залицяльник, полюбовник»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2837&page=120)), «бендю́г»/«бендю́га́»/«биндю́г»/«биндю́га» (є у словниках у значеннях «палка» та «кінь-ломовик»), «розтру́х» (здається, нема в словниках), «финдю́р(ик)» (здається, нема в словниках), «хльор» (здається, нема в словниках) тощо.